# facebook share button not taking meta tags

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using **facebook share button** on my website. I am following facebook documentation to do this. But It is not taking content from meta tags but taking random content from my website. When i try to debug the shared url through facebook debugger It was giving me two warning, which are below:

```
Inferred Property:   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties:  The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
```

But below are the meta tags, which i am using on that page which i want to share.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Welcome to the world of computer science." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://tophat.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/BLOG_code.jpg" />
```

I am using aws server to host my website.**htaccess is enabled is my website**, I think it is because of that.
Can anyone please tell me the reason for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello @Rajat**,

As I reviewed your question, You are using aws server in which you performed htaccess authentication. You just need to remove htaccess authentication and then use facebook debugger tool to scrap your website again. It will help you to clear cache from your website. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) is the link of facebook debugger.

**Note:** You have to remove htaccess authentication because facebook only crawl data from public url's.